# Django Template changing html attribute based on slug and current request

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, slug

When I tried to iterate through a list of post titles to create links in a django template the urls never match the requested path (matching the current web page should alter the formatting on the page for that list item).  When I try and change things, Django spits out a 404 error which doesn't let me diagnose the problem or it "works" but not as expected.

the relevant url patterns (in blog app within project):

```
path('', views.index, name='blog_index'), 
path('<slug:post>', views.blog_post, name='entries')
```

the relevant views functions (in blog app within project):

```
ef index(request):
    try:
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts':blog_posts.keys})
    except:
        raise Http404()

def blog_post(request, post):
    try:
        return render(request, 'blog/post.html', {
            'post_title':post,
            'post_content':blog_posts[],
            'posts':blog_posts.keys
            })
    except:
       raise Http404()
```

the navigation template:

```
<ul>
   {% for post in posts %}
   {% url "blog:entries" "{{post}}" as blog_entry %}
   <li><a href="/blog/{{post}}" {% if request.path == blog_entry %} class="active"{% endif %}>
   <span class="item">{{post}}</span>
   </a></li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I suspect the `{% url "blog:entries" "{{post}}" as blog_entry %}` in the template is not resolving correctly as when I replace the href with `{% blog_entry %}` it causes a 404 error.

I have tried hard coding it in, I have tried different ways of writing the url, I have tried changing the syntax (in case I am doing it incorrectly.  I have checked the page source when I have run tests.   I have never been able to get the class attribute to be "active" when on the matching page.

EDIT: The links all go to the correct pages, however the IF logic in the template does not work.  i.e. None of the changes I have tried make result in `reques.path == blog_entry` resolving as `True`.
Also the above code snippets are part of an App within a project and I have included more of the views.py and urls.py file.  Currently I have the "blog posts" stored in a dictionary at the top of views.py for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul>
   {% for post in posts %}
   {% url "blog:entries" post=post as blog_entry %}
   <li><a href="/blog/{{post}}" {% if request.path == blog_entry %} class="active"{% endif %}>
   <span class="item">{{post}}</span>
   </a></li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello Danijel, thank you for your reply. 
I have included more of my code as I think I have already included your suggestion but I hadn't put them in my initial question.
My problem wasn't getting the links to work but getting the if logic in the template to work.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bad understanding... I edited my previous comment.

Comment: post=post, I thought I had tried that but apparently not.  Cheers, big help.